# Refreshing Dropdown Arrays automatically

Tags: html, angularjs

I have two dropdowns where I am passing two arrays from my angularjs file. One drop down has the names and the other drop down has the subjects. so when a name is selected from the first dropdown subjects related to that name is loaded to the second dropdown. Its working correctly. But if I again select another name from the first drop down instead of showing only subjects related to the secondly selected name subjects related to first name and second name both shows in the second drop down. Im storing these values in two global arrays and passing them to the two dropdowns. How can I display only the related values in the second drop down ?

js

```
$scope.arrayName = [];
$scope.arraySubj = [];

function1()
{
//assigning values to $scope.arrayName;
}
function2(selectedVal)
{
//assigning values to $scope.Subj;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
<select ng-model="a" ng-options="item for item in arrayName" ng-change="function2(a)">
<select ng-model="b" ng-options="item for item in $scope.Subj">
</body>
```

Comment: Share the codes you have done to ask for helps.

Comment: You have syntax errors in your code that are likely showing up in the console of your browser. `function1() {}` and `function2(selectedVal){}` are both invalid.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, whenever `function2(selectedVal)` is called you'll need to reset the subj array to empty. Hopefully, that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be better to just use the built in filter service?

```
<select ng-model="a" ng-options="name as name in arrayName"></select>
<select ng-model="b" ng-options="item as item in arraySubj | filter: customFilter"></select>
```

where

```
$scope.customFilter = function(item, idx, arr) {
    return (does item match whatever the criteria is from $scope.a);
}
```

Instead of rebuilding the $scope.subJ array whenever $scope.a changes?